# Sorting date column in python from csv file - string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
Name,City,Date
"Bobby","NY","20210925"
"Henry","Boston","20210521"
"Linda","Phoenix","20201114"
```

I'm trying to sort based on date:

```
csvfile = open(filename,'r')
data = sorted(csvfile, key = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row["Date"], "%Y%m%d"))
for row in data:
    print(row)
```

However, I'm getting the error below.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

> Message=string indices must be integers
> Source=C:\Users\Henry\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\module1.py
> StackTrace:   File
> "C:\Users\Henry\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\module1.py",
> line 29, in 
> data = sorted(csvfile, key = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row["Date"], "%Y%m%d"))   File
> "C:\Users\Henry\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\module1.py",
> line 29, in main
> data = sorted(csvfile, key = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row["Date"], "%Y%m%d"))   File
> "C:\Users\Henry\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\module1.py",
> line 34, in  (Current frame)
> main()

Comment: You may need to load the CSV into a list, then sort it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas `pd.read_csv` and it will work for you

```
import pandas as pd
filename = "/content/untitled"
pd.read_csv(filename)
```

```
    Name    City    Date
0   Bobby   NY  20210925
1   Henry   Boston  20210521
2   Linda   Phoenix 20201114
```

you can change the date to be in better format

```
Name,City,Date
"Bobby","NY","2021/09/25"
"Henry","Boston","2021/05/21"
"Linda","Phoenix","2020/11/14"
```

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
filename = "/content/untitled"
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df
#output

    Name    City    Date
0   Bobby   NY  2021-09-25
1   Henry   Boston  2021-05-21
2   Linda   Phoenix 2020-11-14
```